# Macbook 16 Intel i9. Big Sur keep rebooting randomly due kernel panic

Tags: kernel-panic, big-sur

I've tried the usual troubleshooting steps (Reset NVRAM, SMC, Safe Boot), but still having the same issue.

```
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c0e
 family: 6 model: 158 stepping: 13 microcode: 222
 signature: 0x906ed
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
 14 error-reporting banks
Processor 14: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0xfe0001c000200135
 IA32_MC3_ADDR(0x40e):   0x000000031555d940
 IA32_MC3_MISC(0x40f):   0x0000000000712485
Processor 15: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0xfe0001c000200135
 IA32_MC3_ADDR(0x40e):   0x000000031555d940
 IA32_MC3_MISC(0x40f):   0x0000000000712485
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 6, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 16 acks but received 1 after 10530998 loops in 1152000000 ticks
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff80105edd19): "Machine Check at 0xffffff8010600af9, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x000000071ff57000, CR3: 0x0000000024595000, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0\n" "RAX: 0x0000000000000060, RBX: 0x0000000000000010, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0xffffffb0dfe0bef0, RBP: 0xffffffb0dfe0bf20, RSI: 0xffffff80113df9c0, RDI: 0xffffff80112504b0\n" "R8:  0xffffffffffffffff, R9:  0x00000ca929217440, R10: 0x0000000000000001, R11: 0xffffff80112a5500\n" "R12: 0x0000000000000060, R13: 0x00000000006f6803, R14: 0x00003217bbbdb0e6, R15: 0x0000000000000006\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000046, RIP: 0xffffff8010600af9, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-7195.60.75/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80103592d0 : 0xffffff80104b9aed 
0xffffff8010359320 : 0xffffff80105fc6e3 
0xffffff8010359360 : 0xffffff80105ecd1a 
0xffffff80103593b0 : 0xffffff801045ea2f 
0xffffff80103593d0 : 0xffffff80104b938d 
0xffffff80103594f0 : 0xffffff80104b9678 
0xffffff8010359560 : 0xffffff8010cbe3ca 
0xffffff80103595d0 : 0xffffff80105edd19 
0xffffff80103596c0 : 0xffffff8010cbedf5 
0xffffff80103596d0 : 0xffffff801045f28f 
0xffffffb0dfe0bf20 : 0xffffff80105ef0a2 
0xffffffb0dfe0bf40 : 0xffffff80104e1119 
0xffffffb0dfe0bf80 : 0xffffff80104e12e8 
0xffffffb0dfe0bfa0 : 0xffffff801045e13e 

Process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
20C69

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 20.2.0: Wed Dec  2 20:39:59 PST 2020; root:xnu-7195.60.75~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 82E2050C-5936-3D24-AD3B-EC4EC5C09E11
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000010200000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8010400000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000010210000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8010410000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8010300000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 55078524125517
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x00003217f7df4339
  Sleep   : 0x00001fc824de0b9c 0x0001511e632081ac 0x00001fbbe89eecb1
  Wake    : 0x00001fc85705d325 0x00015161c1458b0a 0x00001fc83630eb50
last started kext at 34762785588182: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice    1.2 (addr 0xffffff80133ad000, size 40960)
last stopped kext at 35175968802359: >usb.!UUserHCI 1 (addr 0xffffff7fb0d9d000, size 98304)
loaded kexts:
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    4020.6
>!AHIDALSService    1
>AGPM   119
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@fileutil   20.036.15
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    4.0.2
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.0.2
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.2.2
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.2.2
>pmtelemetry    1
>LuaHardwareAccess  1.0.16
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>!AMuxControl2  6.2.2
>!A!IKBLGraphics    16.0.1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    100.2
|IO!BSerialManager  8.0.2f9
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.431
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 16.0.1
>BridgeAudioCommunication   100.2
>AGDCBacklightControl   6.2.2
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   556.60.1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1677.60.23
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    310
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@nke.ppp    1.9
>!AActuatorDriver   4400.28
>!AHIDKeyboard  222
>!AMultitouchDriver 4400.28
>!AInputDeviceSupport   4400.35
>!AHS!BDriver   4020.6
>IO!BHIDDriver  8.0.2f9
@kext.triggers  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
>!AGraphicsControl  6.2.2
|IOAVB!F    900.12
@!AGPUWrangler  6.2.2
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    900.11
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 4.0.2
@kext.AMDSupport    4.0.2
|IOAudio!F  300.6.1
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   439.52
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    8.0.2f9
|IO!BHost!CTransport    8.0.2f9
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.2.2
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  585
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  4.0.2
|IOGraphics!F   585
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>corecapture    1.0.4
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.1.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.1.4
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  289.3
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$!AImage4   3.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   900.11
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 8.0.2f9
|IOReport!F 47
|IO!BPacketLogger   8.0.2f9
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  511.60.2
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  184.40.6
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  436.40.6
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  436.40.6
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 11.1
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: "Machine check" usually means a hardware issue. Does it also crash when booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: Yes. same issue.

Comment: Are you using any peripherals attached to the machine during boot? The last loaded kext indicates USB.

Comment: I think I was using the External Disk for Time Machine. It happened again without the disk connected. I updated the report with that last error. This time I had a cable connected to charge my iPhone without actually the phone.

Comment: I also see `panic(cpu 6...`.   Did you replace any hardware or add any RAM?  I'm not an expert but it all looks hardware-related.  Is it still under warranty?

Comment: No, I did not change any hardware ever. Unfortunately, I have the warranty exired.

Comment: This also happens to my i7 MBP '15. It tends to happen with stress like yours is. It's going to need to be fixed or replaced - if you have AppleCare, that's good - but you can take it to a Genius Bar for free (with appointment) and they'll probably have you send it to get fixed (which should be much cheaper than replacing the computer). If you have the budget you could replace with a new one, the M1 series outperforming the i9 in most cases, and it would be supported for longer.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to the OS -  There are two power nap options, one under battery and one under power adaptor. Just make sure both disable. maybe an USB wakeup bug?

Comment: I disabled the option. Let see if it doesn't happen again. Thanks.

Comment: This won't help. It keeps restarting.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately disabling options in the battery section, won't help you. I did the same and my MacBook pro 16 inc keeps restarting while I'm trying to get in session after simple restart + it also crashes when I totally reset my SSD + install the clean OS.

Comment: I notice that most of the time, It happens when the Macbook is under stress. Docker + IDE + Chrome.